# Encoding bug with an image and file_get_contents in PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding, file-get-contents

I use this code to retrieve and display an image:

```
header("Content-type: image/png"); 
echo file_get_contents(site_domain().image_asset_module_url("header.png",$this->name));
```

on my local WAMP it works, but on the remote server `file_get_contents` returns a wrong-encoded string:

Local:

```
‰PNG  IHDR^jRÀ2¡    pHYsÒÝ~üÿÿIDATxÚì½˜Uõµþ¿`ŠŠÔéÃÕ¨¹&&ù'77¹i¦˜è‰=V:RlH‡™aAlH™B¯Jbh...
```

Remote:

```
�PNG  IHDR^jR�2�    pHYs��~���IDATx����U����`������ը�&&�'77�i��草=V:Rl...
```

If I use `utf8_encode` I get:

```
PNG  IHDR^jRÀ2¡ pHYsÒÝ~üÿÿIDATxÚì½Uõµþ¿`ÔéÃÕ¨¹&&ù'77¹i¦è=V:RlHaAlHB¯Jbh...
```

So I always get a break picture on my remote Server - why and what is the solution?

Comment: have you even try mb_convert_encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *data* is always the same. `file_get_contents` does not alter data in any way. You're also not dealing with text in some encoding, but with binary data. Any sort of text-encoding or conversion thereof does not apply here.

Your first sample is the binary image data as interpreted as Latin-1 encoded text.
Your second sample is the same binary data as interpreted as UTF-8 encoded text.

I.e., the data is fine, the *interpretation* is wrong. The interpretation should be set by the `Content-Type` header, perhaps this is not being set correctly on the remote server. For this problem, inspect the raw HTTP response headers and see [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php).

Comment: The header looks good `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                                    Date: Thu, 30 May 2013 09:01:01 GMT
                                    Server: Apache
                                    Set-Cookie: [506 bytes were stripped]
                                    X-Powered-By: PleskLin
                                    Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
                                    Connection: Keep-Alive
                                    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
                                    Content-Type: image/png`

Comment: And yet you get the output as jumbled text? Compare the HTTP body you receive (which should be the image data) with the raw image data in a hex editor! See if there's any difference, especially any leading bytes at the beginning that shouldn't be there.

Comment: In my http body after `Type: image/png` I have `0d 0a 0d 0a 31 65 37 34 65 0d 0a ef bb bf` and after the hex code is the same code from the image png

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you said; does the file data look like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header ? Or is there extra stuff?

Comment: I found the problem when I put my controllers in utf8 BOM I have a space that ride in my website, in ANSI the space is invisble. Now I have more than to find or is this space, thank you for all !

Answer (score -1):

I would have rather used

```
<?php

$file = 'http://url/to_image.png';
$data = file_get_contents($file);

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $data;
```

Or Can you try this

```
$remoteImage = "http://www.example.com/gifs/logo.gif";
$imginfo = getimagesize($remoteImage);
header("Content-type: $imginfo['mime']");
readfile($remoteImage);
```

Comment: @deceze Its simple!  No use of `site_domain().image_asset_module_url`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not work I still get the same string

Comment: If I did not put `site_domain().image_asset_module_url("header.png", $ this->name)` , And I put the URL directly into hard, anyway I error